# Java Class loading

Tags: java, class, classloader

I want to understand how Java class loaders works. I have read some articles, but there are some things are still unclear to me.

As far as I understand the first class loader is the Bootstrap class loader (BCL). **Is it loaded by the JVM?**

Afterwards, the BCL loads rt.jar library, and the Extension Class Loader (ECL).

In turn, the ECL loads extensions and the Application Class Loader (ACL). The ACL is responsible for loading all user-developed class from the classpath.

Is this description correct?

There some questions:

1. There is only one instance of each classloader exists in memory ? (BCL,ECL,ACL) ?
2. I have looked at delegation principle,but it is a little bit unclear for me. How does it work, let's assume we need load MyClass. First jvm gives this class name to the ACL, and here is unclear thing for me, ACL looks through class path and if there is no such class delegates this work to the parent OR it delegates this work to parent right after calling, I mean JVM gives class name to ACL, it doesn't search for this class gives it to ECL, this CL in turn also doesn't do any work and gives it to BCL, and only if BCL cannot find this class it return it to the lower level (ECL) .... and so on. What is the correct chain ?
3. When we creating custom class loader what is parent class of it ? Application ClassLoader ? Can we specify , for instance ECL. As far as hierarchy of class loaders is not inheritance, we specify parent in constructor. Can we get instance of ECL classloader to specify it in our custom CL as a parent in constructor.
4. Why classes like String , Object and so on don't return any ClassLoadder ?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250656/how-is-the-classloader-for-a-class-chosen?rq=1

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/how-classloader-works-in-java.html;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answers:

1. > As far as I understand the first class loader is the Bootstrap class loader (BCL). Is it loaded by the JVM?

   This is not explicitly defined, but will be most likely written in a native code.
2. > Afterwards, the BCL loads rt.jar library, and the Extension Class Loader (ECL).

   Yes it will load rt.jar (till Java 8 as in Java 9 there will be new module system). Whether it loads the ECL or not is not explicitly defined.
3. > In turn, the ECL loads extensions and the Application Class Loader (ACL). The ACL is responsible for loading all user-developed class from the classpath.

   Yes it loads the extensions and whether it loads the ACL or not is not explicitly defined. ACL loads the classpath entries, indeed.
4. > There is only one instance of each classloader exists in memory ? (BCL,ECL,ACL) ?

   Yes, this is correct. As the class identity is defined as a pair of FQCN and its effective classloader, otherwise it will not work.
5. > I have looked at delegation principle,but it is a little bit unclear for me. How does it work, let's assume we need load MyClass. First jvm gives this class name to the ACL, and here is unclear thing for me, ACL looks through class path and if there is no such class delegates this work to the parent OR it delegates this work to parent right after calling, I mean JVM gives class name to ACL, it doesn't search for this class gives it to ECL, this CL in turn also doesn't do any work and gives it to BCL, and only if BCL cannot find this class it return it to the lower level (ECL) .... and so on. What is the correct chain ?

   **In standard Java, there is parent-first delegation model**, that means classloader will first ask its parent and only then will try to load a class by itself.
6. > When we creating custom class loader what is parent class of it ? Application ClassLoader ? Can we specify , for instance ECL. As far as hierarchy of class loaders is not inheritance, we specify parent in constructor. Can we get instance of ECL classloader to specify it in our custom CL as a parent in constructor.

   **Default parent of your custom classloader is application classloader.**

   The question is why would you need to do it? It is unlikely that your program will behave correctly. Formally you can do this by **`YourClass.class.getClassLoader().getParent()`**.
7. > Why classes like String , Object and so on don't return any ClassLoadder ?

   **Bootstrap classloader is represented as `null` in the API.**